# How to match two fields in MongoDb but one is ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, middleware

I am creating an Interactive platform and I decide to use MongoDB as my DB. I want only the blog owner who is signed in at that as the only person who can delete the blog but What I have currently is bypassing the criteria when using the token of another user
How can I match two fields in Model being one is objectId

My midlleware
It has to pass through authenticated first before proceeding to the next middleware

```js
const blogowner = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  authenticated(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const isblog = await Blog.find({
        $and: [{ _id: req.params.blogid }, { user: { $eq: req.user._id } }],
      });
      if (isblog) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(401).send({ ErrMessage: "action permission denied" });
      }
      console.log("blog owner found");
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({ ErrMessage: error.message });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Make sure that you have cast the id to `ObjectId` for the parameter value to the field which is ObjectId type, which similar questions are commonly asked in the community.

Comment: can you edit my code to give me clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use MongoDB operators and cast ids to `ObjectId`, Mongoose will automatically do that for you, when you're using Mongoose native methods like **find()**, **findOne()** for AND operations.

You can find the document like this.

```
const blogowner = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  authenticated(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const isblog = await Blog.find({ _id: req.params.blogid, user: req.user._id })
      if (isblog) {
        next()
      } else {
        return res.status(401).send({ ErrMessage: 'action permission denied' })
      }
      console.log('blog owner found')
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({ ErrMessage: error.message })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this heads up Neeraj, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it worked well!!

Comment: could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74099002/find-if-user-exist-in-array-mongodb-and-nodejs