# Find if User Exist in array mongodb and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this opportunity model that has this field **likes**, which is an array of users. How do I check first if the user exist already in that array and if they do I pull them and if they don't I push them back I am building a like creteria for posts

Here is my opportunity model

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const OpportunityModel = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  likes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
  image: [
    {
      type: Object,
    },
  ],
  share_with_thoughts: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Shares",
  },
  comments: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment",
  },
  is_opportunity_applied: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});

const Opportunity = mongoose.model("Opportunity", OpportunityModel);
module.exports = Opportunity;
```

What I tried doing but did not work

```js
const likeOrUnlikeOpportunity = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.user._id;
  let opportunityId = req.params.opportunityId;
  let isUserExist = await Opportunity.find({
    $and: [{ _id: opportunityId }, { likes: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } }],
  }).populate("user", "user_id user_name");

  if (isUserExist.length > 0) {
    const unliked = await Opportunity.findByIdAndUpdate(
      opportunityId,
      {
        $pull: { users: userId },
      },
      { new: true }
    ).populate("user", "user_id user_name");

    if (!unliked) {
      res.status(500).send({ ErrMessaage: "an error occured" });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(unliked);
    }
  } else {
    const added = await Opportunity.findByIdAndUpdate(
      opportunityId,
      {
        $push: { users: userId },
      },
      { new: true }
    ).populate("user", "user_id user_name");

    if (!added) {
      res.status(500).send({ ErrMessaage: "an error occured" });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(added);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the action should be dynamic [like | unlike] function, You don't have to chain the function since the like and unlike function/api can't be called at the same time.

Make Your Query Conditional;
Just make sure you have a way to identify between like and unlike.

```js
const {like, postId} = req.body;
let query = {[`${'$' + (like ? 'push' : 'pull')}`]: {likes: userId}};

//assumes that you have the post id
// you can decide not to wait for it to update, just to be sure it did update
await post.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, query).exec()
```

I hope this helps.